# Scrollable Bug Only Showing up on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, ipad

We just launched a new site for a local restaurant and have pretty much squashed all the bugs. Only outstanding one is only manifesting itself on the iPad's Mobile Safari.

There's a background selector at the very bottom of the page. The left and right arrows used to navigate through the background thumbnails animates the div left and right to see more thumbnails.

But on the iPad, the current background thumb (the one with the white border around it), is the only thing that moves. Any idea why this would happen on just the iPad?

http://gravyraleigh.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS in general has issues with scrolling, 4.3 has issues scrolling inside divs, and 5 has issues scrolling inside IFrames. The way we got around this was by writing a function that would determine the width of the content then sized the box appropriately.

Look at jQuery function .width() it will return the actual width of any tag, and allow you to get a value for the width of the content you are using. Best practice for iOS i've found is to change the height of the div based on the width of the viewport, or to use percentage based layouts so that when the viewport changes, the layout can adjust. Scrolling is very buggy and it's best to avoid it if possible until iOS developers fix the issues in iOS 5, however 4.3 will still have these issues.